# Search engine for a custom component

Tags: component, database, view, search

I need to add search engine to my component. In database I have three feilds: name, post, address. How to add searching with this fields separatly? For example in the view I add three fields and search button. When I click the button it searches for matches with some of the fields.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using in your view and any attempt to get the search working that you have tried so far.

Comment: @DavidFritsch I dont' have any attempt to create it. I would like to get the suggestion how to get it. The most obvious variant is to create a model with SQL statement such as `SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE `post` LIKE 'qwe'`. But I suppose that there are some joomla abilities to avoid manual creating of the statements.

Comment: The only Joomla implementation that I know of would be to have it actually tie into the search component with a search plugin (http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin). Otherwise, your best bet is to hook it into your getQuery method in your model.

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to create your own search plugin as is fully documented at [Creating a search plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_search_plugin).

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a feature of Component Creator: the search plugin. http://component-creator.com/en/forum/announcements/35-database-updater-frontend-search-plugin

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @AndrésMaeso and welcome to JSE. Please consider improving your answer with more details. As it stands right now, it provides little information AND seems more like self-promotion. Thanks for understanding.